# Threading-alternatives-Best Approach

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a scenario: I need to compare 350 tables between two databases. So the procedure we following is :

1.Creating 350 temp tables in sql
2.Inserting data in that from DBs
3.Last comparing each temp tables and find the difference.

In this approach:
We are  using a thread that is waiting till the end of step 1.
Then next thread that will wait till the end of 2.

So its taking too much time.IS  there any approach  to do like create one table load data ,  parallely create second and load, like without waiting till the end.

update: this is my sample code:

```
foreach (var bpr in tableDetails)
            {
                var tableName = bpr.TableName;
                ComparisonDataLoadLoadWorkerID(comparisonID, sourceEnvId, targetEnvId, tableName);//creating table and loading from DBs
            }
```

Here loping through each table and creating and loading data.After loading full tables data then comparing . So  I need to wait till the above foreach is ending. WhatI am expecting is if the first table is creating load data and parallely second table creation and dataload should happen. So no need to wait till each table load ends. 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show us some code.

Comment: `1.` do you compare data in tables with the same structure? `2.` why do you need temp tables? to avoid locks on tables? `3.` give a bit context here: why do you need this?

Comment: Some DBMS have the ability to quickly create _[snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)_. If yours could do that, then there would be no need to copy tables: Just make a snapshot, and then compare the tables in the snapshot.

Comment: @mtkachenko:thanks for the reply. comparing data in tables with same structure only. We are fetching data from source and target and inserting into temp tables for comparison. After comparison the changes if any ot no change will bedetected and inserting into another  database.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of the question, you can try to create something like (in pseudocode):

```
var t = new Task(() => /* code that creates the temp table */ );
var last = t
           .continueWith (p => /* code that inserts the data into it */ )
           .continueWith (p => /* code that compares the data */ );
t.Start();
```

Then, you can do this in a loop for all the 350 tables.

That will achieve some parallelism, but keep in mind that your bottleneck will be SqlServer, so don't expect tremendous effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This will aslo work like once all temp tables are created then only data load will happen right?

Comment: No.  It will create a table, then start loading data, then comparing it...  While one table is being created, for another data may be loading.  If you want that data load starts only after all tables are created, then you need a different approach: 1) create a task to create each table.  2) Create task WhenAll for them, and ContinueWith it with a task that spawns tasks to load the data.  3) Do (2) but for comparing data.